How does Terraform resolve docker image tags when updating Cloud Run service?
When running terraform apply I was expecting the google_cloud_run_service.example_service.containers.image to be updated in place, as the image value is set to "${local.image}:latest" and a new image with the same tag but different commit hash has been pushed to the Artifact Registry repository before the apply command was run.
But instead, Terraform found no changes, and did not make any updates.
Why wasn't Terraform able to distinguish between the previous image and the current one, even if they both have the latest tag, but different commit hashes? Am I missing something?
Locals:
locals {
  project_id      = var.project_id
  region          = var.region
  image           = "${var.region}-docker.pkg.dev/${local.project_id}/example-${var.environment_name}/example"
  image_commit    = "${local.image}:$COMMIT_SHA"
  image_latest    = "${local.image}:latest"
  api_key_secret_id = "api-key"
}

Cloud Run service:
resource "google_cloud_run_service" "example_service" {
  project                    = var.project_id
  name                       = "example-${var.environment_name}"
  location                   = var.region
  autogenerate_revision_name = true
  template {
    spec {

      containers {
        image = local.image_latest
        env {
          name  = "ENV"
          value = var.environment_name
        }
        env {
          name = "API_KEY"
          value_from {
            secret_key_ref {
              name = local.api_key_secret_id
              key  = google_secret_manager_secret_version.api_key_secret_version.version
            }
          }
        }
        liveness_probe {
          failure_threshold     = 5
          period_seconds        = 10
          timeout_seconds       = 5
          initial_delay_seconds = 10

          http_get {
            path = "/liveness"
            port = 8080
          }
        }

        startup_probe {
          failure_threshold     = 12
          period_seconds        = 10
          timeout_seconds       = 5
          initial_delay_seconds = 10

          http_get {
            path = "/startup"
            port = 8080
          }
        }
      }
    }
    metadata {
      annotations = {
        "autoscaling.knative.dev/minScale" = "1"
      }
    }
  }

  traffic {
    percent         = 100
    latest_revision = true
  }

  depends_on = [
    google_project_iam_member.compute_default_secret_access,
    google_project_service.cloudrun_google_api,
    google_secret_manager_secret.api_key_secret
  ]
}


According to your config the image value is actually assigned to local.image_commit which is a value that does not appear to change between builds for any reason according to the resolved variable values in the local.image. You probably intended a different value since you stated you wanted different behavior. I am unsure what your intention is here though.

@MatthewSchuchard I was trying out different things and forgot to change it back to local.image_latest. I now edited my comment to reflect that, but it was originally local.image_latest when it did not work. My intention is simply for Terraform to update the Cloud Run image that is being used for the service with the latest image.

See this issue: google_cloud_run_v2_service resource do not detect docker image changes in version "latest" #16679

I'd be inclined to use image_commit if you can as this will very probably change with each image change.
